# Android: ANR "Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF }" on paint.getTextBounds

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have an ANR "Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF }" on the following line of code :

```
 paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
```

This line of code is executed in the method getImageWithMeasures launched like this:

```
 HelloArActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {


                    Bitmap bm = getImageWithMeasures(true, true);
```

I think that this ANR makes my app crashing.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks !

Comment: It seems that your function getImageWithMeasures(boolean, boolean) is taking a long time to be executed and return a bitmap - try to run it in worker thread and send result to main thread, and while it will be executed you can show some progress bar - so the user can understand that there is some action is being processed
You can do that with RxJava - Coroutines (in Kotlin) \